How do I access my Android files from recovery mode with developer mode?
My Nothing Phone (1), Android 14, has entered a spring-bootloop, just showing the block screen for 1 second, then resprings and repeats. This problem caused after I've changed display refresh rate setting via SetEdit programme.
Entering recovery mode and selecting Reboot does not fix the issue, booting in safe mode too.
Is there any way I could access my data? Hoping to get media, apps data and contact lists. By the way, is there any chance that it would possible to encrypt this data in 5-6 years, if there is no other options?

Android user data is encrypted by default and I haven't seen a stock recover with the capability to decrypt user data. But you mentioned safe mode. Does safe mode work? What have you tried in safe mode to recover your device?

I've tried to connect via ABD and Fastboot protocols, phone is available, but it's impossible to mount any partitions. It only allows to flash, nothing else.

I doubt flashing is allowed. in safe mode, use adb to undo whatever you have done

Unfortunately, device asks for confirmation, but it's impossible to confirm.

short-circuit the test points to backup all partitions from edl mode, then try to flash (AVBv2 signed) magisk patched boot.bin (with authorized adb enabled) on locked bootloader. Note: do not factory reset device, keystore in TEE can't be backed up and is lost forever!
